# Not Getting Registered ID using Phonegap push notification v2.7.0

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

for 10 days trying to implement the GCM in PhoneGap without a result, and after  following This link [PhoneGap Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), and I have already setup every thing to enable GCM in android and have followed complete documentation, up to now I am still have found no error without knowing what's wrong in my code?

- I have received this messages after running app in CatLog:

Messages:-

```
11-08 14:51:15.616: V/PushPlugin(1151): execute: action=register
11-08 14:51:15.646: V/PushPlugin(1151): execute: data=[{"senderID":"1014356851653","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"}]
11-08 14:51:15.666: V/PushPlugin(1151): execute: jo={"senderID":"1014356851653","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"}
11-08 14:51:15.666: V/PushPlugin(1151): execute: ECB=onNotificationGCM senderID=1014356851653
11-08 14:51:15.676: D/GCMRegistrar(1151): resetting backoff for org.apache.cordova.example
11-08 14:51:15.776: V/GCMRegistrar(1151): Registering app org.apache.cordova.example of senders 1014356851653
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pushNotification;

            function onDeviceReady() {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

                                document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
                                {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                                      if( $("#home").length > 0)
                                        {
                                                // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                                                //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                                                e.preventDefault();
                                                navigator.app.exitApp();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                navigator.app.backHistory();
                                        }
                                }, false);

                                try 
                                { 
                        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                            pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"1014356851653","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});                // required!
                                        } else {
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                            pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});        // required!
                        }
                }
                                catch(err) 
                                { 
                                        txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                                        txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                                        alert(txt); 
                                } 
            }


            // handle GCM notifications for Android
            function onNotificationGCM(e) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
                                        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                                        {
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                                                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                                                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                                                console.log("regID = " + e.regID);
                                        }
                    break;

                    case 'message':
                            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                            if (e.foreground)
                            {
                                                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                                                        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                                        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                                                        my_media.play();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {        // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                                                        if (e.coldstart)
                                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                                                        else
                                                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                                                }

                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    break;

                    case 'error':
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                    default:
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            }

            function tokenHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
                // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
            }

            function successHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
            }

            function errorHandler (error) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
            }

                        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

         </script>
                <div id="home">
                        <div id="app-status-div">
                                <ul id="app-status-ul">
                                        <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="org.apache.cordova.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.apache.cordova.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application>
<activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="org.apache.cordova.example" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />

</application>
```

also Add plugin in config.XMl

How to make the plugin of GCM working well in Android?

Comment: What Android version are you testing it on? What's the package name of your app?

Comment: same thing here .. any news? https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/395